# Why can't I access Tkinter widgets in an event handler?

Tags: tkinter, event-handling, widget, closures

My aim is to update the same Label object every time the drop-down list selection changes. From what I know, because of closure, the outer environment object, lblResult must be available to the event handler function locationChanged(). But in the handler, lblResult is always None. I tried passing the lblResult object to the handler, declaring lblResult in event handler global, but none worked. If anyone can explain why it's so, how can I fix it, it will be a great help. Thanks.

```
   from tkinter import Label, OptionMenu, StringVar, Tk
    root = Tk()
    
    
    def locationChanged(x):
        lblResult.config(text=x)  # lblResult is None always
        #lblResult = Label(root, text=x).pack() # this works but I want the same Label to be updated
    
    locations=["Select a City...", "Amsterdam,NL", "NewYork,NY,US", "Sydney,NSW,AU", "Toronto,ON,CA"]
    selectedLocation = StringVar()
    ddlLocation = OptionMenu(root, selectedLocation, *locations, command=lambda x: locationChanged(x)).pack()
    lblResult = Label(root, text="").pack()
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First of all you never call `lblResult.pack()`. Also you shouldn't create a widget and call `.pack` on the same line. It can result in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) problem

Comment: The code you posted should never have `lblResult` being `None`.

Comment: @BryanOakley The initial code that I posted missed the .pack() in the label widget creation line. Now I have added that. sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def location_changed(x):
    # Show the label
    lbl_result.pack()
    # Update the widget's text
    lbl_result.config(text=x)

root = tk.Tk()

locations = ("Select a City...", "Amsterdam,NL", "NewYork,NY,US", "Sydney,NSW,AU", "Toronto,ON,CA")

selected_location = tk.StringVar()
ddl_location = tk.OptionMenu(root, selected_location, *locations, command=location_changed)
ddl_location.pack()

lbl_result = tk.Label(root, text="")

root.mainloop()
```

You need to call `lblResult.pack()` inside the function. Also please make sure you don't call `.pack()` on the same line that you create your widgets or you might run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I completely missed that I am storing the return value of pack() in lblResult. Also splitting the object creation line, into two like the following also fixes it. Thanks again.

lblResult = Label(root, text="")
lblResult.pack()